# Why is the API User Only permission missing in my Developer Edition?

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, developer-edition

I've just created a Developer Edition to test out some profile and permission set related functionality and when trying to save my Apex class I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid field PermissionsApiUserOnly for SObject PermissionSet

After taking a look in Workbench the `PermissionsApiUserOnly` field does not exist on the `Profile` or `PermissionSet` objects in my Developer Edition, however if I look at the `Profile` and `PermissionSet` objects for our Production organization it does exist.

At first I thought it was an optional feature that we'd turned on in our Production organization, but after a quick search I can't find any documentation to support this theory.

Why is the `ApiUserOnly` permission not available in my Developer Edition, and is it possible to make this permission available?

Answer (score 2):

This option is not available for the Developer Org as it makes no sense as we do not use the Developer Org for the purpose of Deployment (Production).Its a org provided by Salesforce just to practice the features efficiently. Hope the answer helped you.